# Enter text in input of sub component then updates father component state are always interrupted in React？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Writing a react today meets a very strange problem. I get the data in the parent component and then pass it to the child component. There are four types of child components, but the third one (as shown below) is input in the input. The time is always interrupted, but the other three can run normally, so the problem is where the source code is attached below, the simulation data has been written in the code, any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

the problem image url is：https://assets.asifx.com/QQ20190130-141357.gif

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { message, Icon, Button, Table, Modal, Input, Select, Drawer, Form, Col, Row, DatePicker, } from 'antd';


class ListGroup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      addText: '',
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  }

  onAdd = () => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    let { data } = this.props;
    const { addText } = this.state;
    if (typeof onChange === 'function') {
      if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
        data = [];
      }
      data.push(addText);
      onChange(data);
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    const { data, onChange } = this.props;
    if (data[e.target.name] && typeof onChange === 'function') {
      data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
      onChange(data);
    }
  }

  onDelete = (index) => {
    const { data, onChange } = this.props;
    if (data[index] && typeof onChange === 'function') {
      data.splice(index, 1);
      onChange(data);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { addText } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Input.Group compact style={{ marginBottom: '24px' }}>
          <Input key='addinput' style={{ width: '84%' }} value={addText} onChange={e => this.setState({ addText: e.target.value })} />
          <Button key='addbutton' style={{ width: '16%' }} type='primary' onClick={this.onAdd}>增加</Button>
        </Input.Group>
        {
          (Array.isArray(data) && data || []).map((item, i) => <Input.Group compact>
            <Input key={i} name={i} style={{ width: '84%' }} value={item} onChange={this.onChange} />
            <Button style={{ width: '16%' }} type='danger' onClick={e => this.onDelete(i)}>删除</Button>
          </Input.Group>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Dict extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      addText1: '',
      addText2: '',
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  }

  onAdd = () => {
    const { data, onChange } = this.props;
    const { addText1, addText2 } = this.state;
    if (typeof onChange === 'function') {
      if (!Array.isArray(data)) {
        data = [];
      }
      data.unshift([addText1, addText2]);
      onChange(data);
      this.setState({ addText1: '', addText2: '' });
    }
  }

  onDelete = (index) => {
    const { data, onChange } = this.props;
    if (data[index] && typeof onChange === 'function') {
      data.splice(index, 1);
      onChange(data);
    }
  }

  onKeyChange = (index, value) => {
    const { data, onChange } = this.props;
    if (data[index] && typeof onChange === 'function') {
      data[index][0] = value;
      onChange(data);
    }
  }

  onValueChange = (index, value) => {
    const { data, onChange } = this.props;
    if (data[index] && typeof onChange === 'function') {
      data[index][1] = value;
      onChange(data);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { addText1, addText2 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Input.Group key='add' compact style={{ marginBottom: '24px' }}>
          <Input key='addinput1' style={{ width: '24%' }} value={addText1} onChange={e => this.setState({ addText1: e.target.value })} />
          <Input key='addinput2' style={{ width: '60%' }} value={addText2} onChange={e => this.setState({ addText2: e.target.value })} />
          <Button key='addbutton' style={{ width: '16%' }} type='primary' onClick={this.onAdd}>增加</Button>
        </Input.Group>
        {
          (Array.isArray(data) && data || []).map((item, i) =>
            <Input.Group key={i} compact>
              <Input style={{ width: '24%' }} key={`key${item}`} name={`key${item}`} value={item[0]} onChange={e => this.onKeyChange(i, e.target.value)} />
              <Input style={{ width: '60%' }} key={`val${item}`} name={`val${item}`} value={item[1]} onChange={e => this.onValueChange(i, e.target.value)} />
              <Button style={{ width: '16%' }} type='danger' onClick={e => this.onDelete(i)}>删除</Button>
            </Input.Group>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      visible: false,
      confirmLoading: false,
      roleOptions: [],
      searchText: '',
      data: [],
      current: 1,
      pageSize: 10,
      total: 0,
      info: {},
      columns: [
        {
          title: '序号',
          dataIndex: 'key',
          key: 'key'
        },
        {
          title: '类型',
          dataIndex: 'type',
          key: 'type'
        },
        {
          title: '描述',
          dataIndex: 'desc',
          key: 'desc'
        },
        {
          title: '变量',
          dataIndex: 'variable',
          key: 'variable'
        },
        {
          title: '操作',
          key: 'operation',
          render: item =>
            <span>
              <a
                href='javascript:;'
                onClick={e => { this.setState({ visible: true, info: item }) }}
              >
                编辑
            </a>
              &nbsp;|&nbsp;
              <a
                href='javascript:;'
                onClick={e => this.onDelete(item.id, item.isActive)}
              >
                删除
              </a>
            </span>
        }
      ],
    }

    this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);
    this.handleOk = this.handleOk.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { current, pageSize, searchText } = this.state;
    this.getData(current, pageSize, searchText);
  }

  getDataFromProps = (objData) => {
    let data = [];
    (Object.keys(objData) || []).forEach(item => {
      data.push([item, objData[item]]);
    });
    return data;
  }

  async getData(current = this.state.current, pageSize = this.state.pageSize, searchText = this.state.searchText) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    let data = [], total = 0;
    try {
      // const resp = await fetch(`http://192.168.1.164:10086/bot/api/query_config?index=${current}&page_size=${pageSize}&query=${searchText}`, {
      //   method: 'GET',
      //   headers: {
      //     // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      //   },
      //   mode: 'cors',
      // });
      // const body = await resp.json();

      const body = {
        data: {
          'data': [
            {
              'id': 1,
              'desc': '用户介绍',
              'variable': 'PERSON_INTRO_LIST',
              'value': [
                '进群须知 1. 最多邀请琥珀进5个群 2. 群人数需要在7-100之间,否则无法激活. 琥珀暂不支持私聊,进群后才能互动',
                '安达斯',
                '阿山东济南'
              ],
              'type': 'list'
            },
            {
              'id': 2,
              'desc': '机器人名称',
              'variable': 'BOT_NAME',
              'value': '琥珀',
              'type': 'text'
            },
            {
              'id': 18,
              'desc': '欢迎语',
              'variable': 'GREET_MAPPING_DICT',
              'value': {
                '早上': 'morning',
                '早晨好': 'morning',
                '早安': 'morning',
                '上午好': 'morning',
                '中午好': 'noon_one',
                '午安': 'noon_two',
                '下午好': 'afternoon',
                '你好': 'hello',
                'hello': 'hello',
                'Hello': 'hello',
                'hi': 'hello',
                'Hi': 'hello',
                '嗨': 'hello',
                '好久不见': 'hello',
                '晚上好': 'night_one',
                '晚安': 'night_two',
                '在吗': 'is_here',
                '在不': 'is_here',
                '在不在': 'is_here'
              },
              'type': 'dict'
            },
            {
              'id': 17,
              'desc': '打招呼字典',
              'variable': 'HAIL_DICT',
              'value': {
                'hello': [
                  'Hi～你好哇～',
                  '你好你好,你有空陪我聊天了吗',
                  '嗯嗯,请多多关照~',
                  '你好呀,我是琥珀,来自瓦歌世界,初来地球,以后请多多关照~',
                  '你好呀,你今天不出去玩嘛'
                ],
                'morning': [
                  '新的一天又开始咯～希望你可以元气满满哦～',
                  '早上好哦～早饭要次好哦',
                  '早上好哇～新的一天又开始啦~',
                  '早上好哦～',
                  '早上好～虽然还没睡醒,但要起床准备奋斗啦～',
                  '早上好~'
                ],
                'noon_one': [
                  '中午好哦～吃个好饭好好犒劳自己～',
                  '中午好啊～',
                  '中午好啊～你准备吃什么呀',
                  '中午好啊～我刚吃完饭～',
                  '中午好,吃饭了没？'
                ],
                'afternoon': [
                  '下午好啊～刚刚睡醒好困哦～',
                  '下午好啊～刚刚睡醒～',
                  '下午好啊～',
                  '下午好啊～累的时候可以跟我聊会天喔～'
                ],
                'night_one': [
                  '晚上好呀～吃过饭了嘛',
                  '晚上好呀～辛苦了一天咯～是时候放松一下啦',
                  '晚上好呀～',
                  '晚上好呀～有空多找我聊天哦～',
                  '晚上好~'
                ],
                'noon_two': [
                  '么么哒～午安～',
                  '么么哒～睡觉咯～午安～',
                  '么么哒～午觉完下午精神更好哦～午安～',
                  '么么哒～祝好梦～午安～',
                  '么么哒～一起睡哦～午安～',
                  '午安~'
                ],
                'night_two': [
                  '么么哒～晚安～',
                  '么么哒～睡觉咯～晚安～',
                  '么么哒～早睡早起身体好～晚安～',
                  '么么哒～祝好梦～晚安～',
                  '么么哒～一起睡哦～晚安～',
                  '晚安~'
                ],
                'is_here': [
                  '嗯嗯,我在~',
                  '嗯嗯,我一直在你身边~',
                  '嗯嗯,我一直在阿斯顿',
                  '我在~我在~',
                  '冒泡~',
                  '在呀',
                  '爱上的框架内'
                ]
              },
              'type': 'list_dict'
            },
          ],
          page_info: {
            total: 4
          }
        }
      }

      total = body.data.page_info.total;

      data = body.data.data.map((item, i) => {
        item.key = (current - 1) * pageSize + i + 1;
        if (item.type === 'dict') {
          item.value = this.getDataFromProps(item.value);
        }
        return item;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      message.error(`读取用户信息失败`);
    }

    this.setState({ data, total, isLoading: false });
  }

  onSearch(event) {
    const { pageSize } = this.setState;
    const searchText = event.target.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    this.setState({ searchText, current: 1 });

    if (this.delaySearch) {
      clearTimeout(this.delaySearch);
    }
    this.delaySearch = setTimeout(e => this.getData(1, pageSize, searchText), 500);
  }

  onPageChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({ current: value });
    this.getData(value);
  }

  async onDelete(id, isActive) {
    try {
      // const resp = await gateway.jsonRequest('PATCH', `/api/v2/auth/users/${id}`, {
      //   data: {
      //     confirmed: !isActive,
      //   }
      // });

      // this.getData(this.current, this.pageSize, this.searchText);
    } catch (error) {
      message.error(`状态修改失败`);
    }
  }

  toPropsData(data) {
    const obj = {};
    (Array.isArray(data) && data || []).forEach(item => {
      obj[item[0]] = item[1];
    })
    return obj;
  }

  async handleOk() {
    const { info } = this.state
    this.setState({ confirmLoading: true });

    if (info.type == 'dict') {
      info.value = this.toPropsData(info.value);
    }

    try {
      if (info.id) {
        const resp = await fetch(`http://192.168.1.164:10086/bot/api/update_config`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          mode: 'cors',
          body: JSON.stringify({ ...info }),
        });
        const body = await resp.json();
      }
      // else {
      //   itemInfo.maState = 1;
      //   itemInfo.password = '123456';
      //   const resp = await gateway.jsonRequest('POST', `/api/v2/auth/users/${itemInfo.id}`,
      //     {
      //       data: itemInfo
      //     }
      //   );
      // }

      this.setState({ visible: false });
    } catch (error) {
      message.error(`提交失败`);
    }

    this.setState({ confirmLoading: false });
    this.getData();
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false, info: {} });
  }

  async onUserActiveChange(dataItem) {
    dataItem.maState = !dataItem.isActive ? 1 : 0;
    dataItem.maId = dataItem.id;
    try {
      // await gateway.jsonRequest(
      //   'POST',
      //   `/datamanage/manage/sys/master/modify`,
      //   {
      //     data: dataItem
      //   }
      // );
    } catch (error) {
      message.error(`更新失败`);
    }

    this.getData(this.current, this.pageSize, this.searchText);
  }

  renderTypeList() {

  }

  renderTypeValue(info) {
    const { type, value } = info;
    let renderTypeHTML = '';
    switch (type) {
      case 'text':
        renderTypeHTML = <Input.TextArea rows={4} value={value} onChange={e => { info.value = e.target.value; this.setState({ info }) }} placeholder='输入 text 类型的值' />;
        break;
      case 'list':
        renderTypeHTML = <ListGroup data={value} onChange={data => { info.value = data; this.setState({ info }); }} />
        break;
      case 'dict':
        renderTypeHTML = <Dict data={value} onChange={data => { info.value = data; this.setState({ info }); }} />
        break;
      case 'list_dict':
        renderTypeHTML = (Object.keys(value) || []).map(key =>
          <Form.Item label={key}>
            <ListGroup data={value[key]} onChange={data => { info.value[key] = data; this.setState({ info }); }} />
          </Form.Item>)
        break;
    }
    return renderTypeHTML;
  }

  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const { isLoading, visible, confirmLoading, roleOptions, searchText, data, info, columns, current, pageSize, total,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className='users'>
        <div className='topbar'>
          <Input.Search
            className='search'
            placeholder='请输入姓名'
            value={searchText}
            onChange={this.onSearch}
          />
          {/* <Button
              className='button-add'
              onClick={e => {
                setVisible(true);
                setInfo(info);
              }}
            >
              <Icon type='plus' />
            </Button> */}
        </div>
        <div className='list'>
          <Table
            loading={isLoading}
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={data}
            pagination={{
              current,
              pageSize,
              total,
              onChange: this.onPageChange
            }}
          />
        </div>

        <Drawer
          title='信息维护'
          width={720}
          onClose={this.handleCancel}
          visible={visible}
          style={{
            overflow: 'auto',
            height: 'calc(100% - 108px)',
            paddingBottom: '108px',
          }}
        >
          <Form layout='vertical' hideRequiredMark>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={20}>
                <Form.Item label='描述'>
                  <Input placeholder='请输入描述' value={info.desc} onChange={e => { info.desc = e.target.value; this.setState({ info }) }} />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label='类型'>
                  <Select placeholder='请选择类型' value={info.type} onChange={value => { info.type = value; this.setState({ info }) }}>
                    <Select.Option value='text'>文本</Select.Option>
                    <Select.Option value='list'>列表</Select.Option>
                    <Select.Option value='dict'>字典</Select.Option>
                    <Select.Option value='list_dict'>字典列表</Select.Option>
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col span={12}>
                <Form.Item label='变量'>
                  <Input placeholder='请输入描述' value={info.variable} onChange={e => { info.variable = e.target.value; this.setState({ info }) }} />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row gutter={16}>
              <Col span={20}>
                <Form.Item label='值'>
                  {this.renderTypeValue(info)}
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form>
          <div
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              left: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              width: '100%',
              borderTop: '1px solid #e9e9e9',
              padding: '10px 16px',
              background: '#fff',
              textAlign: 'right',
            }}
          >
            <Button onClick={this.handleCancel} style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
              取消
            </Button>
            <Button confirmLoading={confirmLoading} onClick={e => this.handleOk()} type='primary'>
              确认
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. The image doesn't illustrate it clearly, too. 'Interrupt' isn't a term. Please, describe in details whats going on and how this differs from desired behaviour.

Comment: i am already update problem views picture in my server， can u see it？